# What is the purpose of this diode in the battery management system schematic?

Tags: batteries, bms

I have a doubt about the function of the diode D6 shown in this [schematic](https://github.com/ceech/BQ76920-BMS/blob/master/Schematic_01.png)

[image]

The schematic is for a battery management system and the diode is between the +,- terminals of the total voltage:

[image]

I do not know about that diode since I could not find its datasheet and I also looked for different diode symbols but no succeed, I guess it is a kind of schottky diode and it is to protect against reverse polarity when charging the battery pack.

Could somebody explain me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D6 is an TVS diode. It's an ESD supressor, as PACK+ signal is placed in the connector, it's susceptible to receive and ESD if someone touch the pin or something. For that reason, a TVS is placed to avoid damage other circuitry because of that event. It's a safety feature.
Here is the datasheet of the diode if you want to have a look to it: https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0000285740_1-2541913.pdf
;)

Comment: Could I supress that diode from my schematic? since in the datasheet of the integrated circuit BMS it is not included in the typical application?

Comment: Yes, you can. It does not add any funcionality and should not affect, unless you have an ESD event.